# How to calculate magnitudes in photometry?

Tags: spectroscopy, photometry

I have a passband filter $b$ and a spectrum (SED) $f_{\lambda}(\lambda)$. Often the formula I find to get the flux in that filter $F_b$ is
$$F_{b}=\dfrac{\int f_{\lambda}(\lambda) T_{b}(\lambda)d\lambda}{\int T_{b}(\lambda)d\lambda}\,,$$
where $T_b$ is the filter response in band $b$, which is similar to the filters shown in figure 2 of [The PLAsTiCC team et al (2018)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1810.00001.pdf).

However, when I try to compute a apparent magnitude, I get the formula
$$m_b=-2.5\log_{10}\left(\dfrac{\int f_{\lambda}(\lambda)\,\lambda\,T_{b}(\lambda)d\lambda}{\int T_{b}(\lambda)\,\lambda\,d\lambda}\right)\,.$$

I don't understand from where does the $\lambda$ in the second formula arises, since I thought that
$$m_b=-2.5\log_{10}\left(\dfrac{F_b}{F_{\mathrm{reference}}}\right)\,.$$

For example, [Casagrande & VandenBerg (2014)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.6095.pdf) show both expressions in equations 1 and 3. However [Bessell & Murphy (2012)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1112.2698.pdf) (eq. 2) and [Hogg, Baldry, Blanton, & Eisenstein (2002)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/0210394.pdf) (eq. 4) only show the second approach. Additionally, [Hogg (2000)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/astro-ph/9905116.pdf) shows the K-correction without the added $\lambda$'s:
$$K=-2.5\log_{10}\left(\dfrac{1}{(1+z)}\dfrac{L_{\lambda/(1+z)}}{L_{\lambda}}\right)\,.$$

I don't know how to reconcile these different views. Can you help me?

Comment: @usernumber, I have fixed the link. When I feed equation (1) into equation (3), the $\lambda$ factor does not appear. That is why I am confused.

Comment: @usernumber there's an additional lambda in the denominator's integral